# Enclosed by '"' Using LOAD DATA INFILE Worked Then Suddenly It Doesn't

Tags: mysql

I'm new with mysql and encountered several issues with Load Data Infile when I tried to create a 23k-record table. So I started again with a small 5-record 2-column CSV file until I finally got it.
I tried this with the earthquake.csv three times (creating different tables with same structure) and it always work.

```
mysql> LOAD DATA INFILE "C:\\ProgramData\\MySQL\\MySQL Server 8.0\\Uploads\\earthquakes.csv"
    -> INTO TABLE sql_earthquakes.tremblor
    -> FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
    -> ENCLOSED BY '"'
    -> LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
    -> IGNORE 1 LINES;

Query OK, 23119 rows affected (0.66 sec)
Records: 23119  Deleted: 0  Skipped: 0  Warnings: 0
```

(I'm using command line btw, but I'm sure you already know that.)

But when I tried again with another csv file, i get the message --

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ENCLOSED BY '"'
IGNORE 1 LINES' at line 5
```

I used the same QUERY as with the earthquakes table and just changed the csv file & table file name.

NOW even when I tried to it again with the simple file & earthquakes.csv, I always get ERROR 1064! I couldn't understand why 'ENCLOSED BY '"'' doesn't work now when I documented everything and copy-pasted the same QUERY every time.

Note: Not sure if it matters, but local_infile is'ON'.

***** Add'l INFO

```
mysql> show tables;
+---------------------------+
| Tables_in_sql_earthquakes |
+---------------------------+
| tremblor                  |
+---------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> create table tremblor2 (
    -> earthquake_id int not null,
    -> occurred_on date, -- varchar(20),
    -> latitude decimal(10,3),
    -> longitude decimal(10,3),
    -> depth decimal(9,2),
    -> magnitude decimal(5,2),
    -> calculation_method varchar(5),
    -> network_id varchar(50),
    -> place varchar(100),
    -> cause varchar(20),
    -> primary key (earthquake_id)
    -> );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.07 sec)

mysql> LOAD DATA INFILE "C:\\ProgramData\\MySQL\\MySQL Server 8.0\\Uploads\\earthquakes.csv"
    -> INTO TABLE sql_earthquakes.tremblor2
    -> FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
    -> LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
    -> ENCLOSED BY '"'
    -> IGNORE 1 LINES;
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ENCLOSED BY '"'
IGNORE 1 LINES' at line 5
mysql>
mysql> LOAD DATA INFILE "C:\\ProgramData\\MySQL\\MySQL Server 8.0\\Uploads\\earthquakes.csv"
    -> INTO TABLE sql_earthquakes.tremblor2
    -> FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
    -> ENCLOSED BY '"'
    -> LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
    -> IGNORE 1 LINES;
Query OK, 23119 rows affected, 27759 warnings (0.62 sec)
Records: 23119  Deleted: 0  Skipped: 0  Warnings: 27759
```

Comment: Post the actual command that gives the error. Probably, you've lost (or added) a quote somewhere.

Comment: Do not use double quote chars for string literals (filename in your case) quoting - they must be used primarily for JSON paths/values quoting.

Comment: Not sure if you've seen my add'l comments about swapping LINES TERMINATED BY '"' and ENCLOSED BY '"' which ran the QUERY successfully.  so does this mean that the commands are in the wrong sequence? Thanks for your help.

Comment: To Akina - Yes, it does work with forward slash on the filename. Thanks again